# Render GUI above omxplayer on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, layer, always-on-top, omxplayer

currently I am trying to show my own UI and a third party virtual keyboard above the video which is displayed by omxplayer.
I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 (which is the reason for using omxplayer).

I am starting omxplayer from command line. I found the `--layer n` option but however it does not seem to change anything.

Did anyone ever come across something similar?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far to draw on top? How do you draw your own UI? Do you have the source code for the virtual keyboard? If you start the omxplayer with --layer n then you have to draw on layer n+1 or higher.

Comment: We are using java.swing for UI. And yes, we have access to the omxplayer source code. However it is not working, for sure I tried to draw the omxplayer behind the UI, I guess omxplayer writes directly into the framebuffer and this causes the problem.